# Как правильно выводить массив в столбик?

Tags: php

Как лучше всего и более правильно выводить в столбик массив ? использовать br ?

```
function Main($menu){
  foreach ($menu as $value) {
    echo $value.' </br>';
}}
```

Comment: например для отладки, очень красиво делать так
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($menu);
print_r('</pre>');

Comment: Обычно на `print_r('<pre>')` ругается. Лучше `print('<pre>');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и списком

```
function Main($menu){
  echo '<UL>';//<OL>
  foreach ($menu as $value) {
    echo '<LI>',$value,' </LI>';
  }
  echo '</UL>';//</OL>
}
```

Но и приведенный пример будет столбиком